# Immutable primitive types

Tags: javascript

Why can't the following argument be made against the claim that primitive types are immutable in Javascript:

```
var $b = false;
$b = true;
alert($b); //-> true
```

I am misunderstanding what it means for a variable to immutable.

Comment: A variable that is immutable can't be changed. AFAIK there is no such thing in JavaScript.

Comment: @ppecher wonderful question, I had almost similar problem in understanding how primitive datatypes are immutable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Values** are immutable; **variables** are not.

`$b = true` changes `$b` to contain the `true` value.
The immutable `false` value is not changed.

Some languages support immutable variables as well (C++'s `const`, Java's `final`, or C#'s `readonly`); Javascript does not.

Comment: So, if I have understood it correctly, then in contrast to C, in JavaScript, if you have a memory location referenced to by say, var x = 1; having the content 0000000000000001 then "immutability" implies that we can't change the memory lcoation's contents to say, 0000000000000011. If this is the case then, if I write var x=1; x=2; everytime JavaScript will provide me with a new memory location and garbage-collect the older unattended one?

Comment: @pulp_fiction: No; that's completely wrong.  It means that you can't change the value `0` to become `1`.

Answer (score 0):

An immutable variable is one that can't be changed, like a constant.  Unfortunately, there are no true immutable variables in JavaScript (at least that I am aware of).

The closest you can get is by using a closure with a getter method.

Answer (score 0):

Scope is mutable, `true` and `false` are not.
You just showed that scope is mutable, and nothing about whether or not `true` or `false` are mutable.